# How to copy a list of directories containing files with specific extension?

Tags: bash, makefile

The following is my directory structure:

```
Makefile
folder1
    file1.c
    foo.txt
folder2
    file2.c
    foo.txt
folder3
    file3.c
    foo.txt
```

I'm trying to create a folder named `dest` in the same directory and then copy `folder1` and `folder2` with only `.c` files contained.

So the resulting `dest` folder should be like the following:

```
dest
    folder1
        file1.c
    folder2
        file2.c
```

EDIT: I could do this with the following:

```
all:
    mkdir -p dest/folder1
    mkdir -p dest/folder2
    cp folder1/*.c dest/folder1
    cp folder2/*.c dest/folder2
```

But would there be a way to rewrite this using the list of directories to copy so I can easily update later? (e.g. `COPYDIRS = folder1 folder2`)

P.S: I'm using macOS but would like to find a cross-platform solution.

Answer (score -1):

Here's how it could be done with a static pattern rule in GNU make 4.1 (answer edited to avoid `cp`'s `--parents` option which wasn't introduced until the late 1990s it seems):

EDIT #2: `-t` option also avoided.

```
dstDir := dest
srcC   := $(wildcard folder1/*.c folder2/*.c)
dstC   := $(addprefix $(dstDir)/,$(srcC))

.PHONY: all
all : $(dstC)
$(dstC) : $(dstDir)/%.c : %.c | $(addsuffix .,$(dir $(dstC)))
    cp $< $(@D)

%/. : ; $(if $(wildcard $@),,mkdir -p $(@D))
```

Output:

```
mkdir -p dest/folder1
mkdir -p dest/folder2
cp folder1/file1.c dest/folder1
cp folder2/file2.c dest/folder2
```

Comment: This doesn't work. It says `cp: illegal option -- -`

Comment: You must be using MacOS.  MacOS has lame command line tools compared to something more advanced / functional like GNU/Linux.  If you want an answer which is specific to your particular operating system, you have to specify what operating system you are using in your question.  Although I agree the answer should make more clear that it requires more modern version of `cp`.